# Installing software in Kali Linux

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux

I'm unable to install any software in Kali Linux.

I tried to fix it by the solution given online. According to that solution, first open terminal and then type "gedit etc/apt/source.list" and then if I get anything in that file then delete it and type

> deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non free
>   deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non free

save, and close it.

But after pressing of save button I got a message

" Could not find the file"/root/etc/apt/source.list; Please check that you typed the location correctly and try again".

So what should I do to fix it.

Comment: I strongly urge you to read the official Kali Linux post about who should be using Kali: https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux. Quite frankly, if you need to ask this question, you really shouldn't be using Kali since you will have a _lot_ of difficulty with it. Start with a normal Linux and install any Kali tools you want there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run `gedit /etc/apt/source.list`, not `gedit etc/apt/source.list`. The file you are looking for is in the `/etc/apt` directory. If you try to open `etc/apt/source.list`, `gedit` will look for a directory called `apt` in your current directory, which is `/root`.